# SBT 1.4.0 console no longer accepting input in SublimeSBT

Tags: scala, sbt, sublimetext3

I have used SublimeSBT with SBT for many years & versions, recently SBT 1.3.13 - it has been fantastic. With sbt 1.4, the console displays ANSI escape codes & doesn't seem to accept my sbt commands.

[image: The prompt is ANSI escape codes]

Comment: Is there an option to turn off color in SBT? Also, your image is tiny and completely illegible. Please don't post images of text, copy it into your question and use the code formatting tool.

Comment: sounds like you should open an issue in the SublimeSBT issue tracker